# Installing the Polynomials Package on Jupyter

Tags: julia

Is there a reason why this isn't working to install the Polynomials package?

```
Pkg.add("Polynomials")

using Polynomials
```

I tried running it in Julia terminal outside of Jupyter and that didn't work either.

I followed these instructions: https://juliamath.github.io/Polynomials.jl/v0.4/. And I can run Julia in Juptyerlab.

The error it gives me is as follows:
[image]

Comment: what instructions did you follow to install IJulia? Are you able to run Julia in Jupyterlab? What does Jupyterlab show when you try to import `Polynomials`?

Comment: I just used this: https://juliamath.github.io/Polynomials.jl/v0.4/. And yeah I can run Julia in Juptyerlab and the error it gives me is as follows: https://imgur.com/P9ZIv0e

Comment: Hmm very strange error. Try quitting out of jupyter, remove `~/.julia/registries/General` or back it up somewhere, and try what you did again. See this thread https://discourse.julialang.org/t/registry-toml-missing/24152

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while installing another Julia package. I deleted the folder in

`C:\Users\Hp\.julia\registries\General`

and re-installed the package and it worked for me.

**Note:** After deleting the folder it will rebuild the registries, so it might take some time to import the package(s).

Comment: Registries sometimes crash if you stop package installation by pressing Ctrl+C. This might be the possible case here.

Comment: Maybe. but after installing some packages, I got the error for a certain package (I forgot the name of the package). But I haven't faced the error since I deleted the C:\Users\Hp\.julia\registries\General folder.